# Undefined data when sending Javascript Object with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, javascript-objects

Let's say I'm trying to send a data to PHP and receive it using pure Javascript.

So when I'm sending a string `"login="+1+"&username="+username+"&password="+password;` with Ajax It's all ok but what about an Object? in this case, my PHP code always telling `username` and `password` are Undefined indexes.

**HTML Document :**

```
<body>
<form id="loginform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"  id="username" required autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" required><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
        document.getElementById("loginform").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

            var data = {// ---- there is my Object -----
                login: 1,
                username: username,
                password: password
            }

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            xhr.onload = function() {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }

            xhr.send(data);
        });
</script>
</body>
```

**PHP Document :**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        echo($username . " , " . $password);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what about an Object?

`send()` doesn't expect to be passed a plain object, so it converts it by calling its `toString()` method, which gives you `"[object Object]"`, which (obviously) isn't URL encoded data.

Not only does PHP not understand it, but the data you want to send isn't included in it in the first place.

---

If you have an object, you need to convert it into a format that you can decode on the server.

Continuing to use form encoded data is the simplest approach.

```js
var data = {
  login: 1,
  username: "example",
  password: "example"
};

var key_value_pairs = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  key_value_pairs.push(
    encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key])
  );
})

var url_encoded_string = key_value_pairs.join("&");

console.log(url_encoded_string);
```

---

You could also send the data using a different format. PHP understands multipart MIME encoding which you can generate with a FormData object.

```
var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("loginform"));
form_data.append("login", "1");
xhr.send(form_data);
```

If you do this, **do not** override the Content-Type with:

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
> ```

XMLHttpRequest will generate the correct-content type, with the multipart MIME boundary parameter from the FormData object.

---

You could also encode the data with a different data format, such as JSON:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

… but, **and this is a big but**, PHP does not know how to decode JSON formatted requests and will **not** automatically populate `$_POST`.

You would need to change the PHP to read the data:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input')
$data = json_decode($json));
var_dump($data);
```